# Erro de indentação no Python deve ser considerado erro de digitação?

Tags: debate

É sabido para muitos que o Python faz uso da indentação para definir os blocos lógicos, distinguindo-se de outras linguagens que costumam utilizar as chaves, `{}`.

```
if true:
    print('Isto pertence ao if')
print('Isto NÃO pertence ao if')
```

No site, temos algumas perguntas que resumem-se a "sua indentação está errada". Dado que a indentação é uma particularidade intrínseca da linguagem, devemos considerar erros de indentação como erros de digitação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A citar algumas perguntas:

1. [Exercício de python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78630/5878)
2. [Erro na função Python ("is not defined")](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346663/5878)
3. [NameError: name 'Janela' is not defined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346389/5878)
4. [Por que essa função fatorial não funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330277/5878)
5. [Por quê o print não retorna todos os itens de uma lista?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306265/5878)
6. [Erro na indentação em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/289942/5878)
7. [Extrair e printar valores específicos de um xml usando Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293864/5878)
8. [Erro de sintaxe no if else](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244026/5878)
9. [Função que some os valores dentro da lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253026/5878)
10. [SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233001/5878)
11. [Erro de sintaxe em sistemas if and elif](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288075/5878)

E essas são apenas algumas que estão abertas, nem considerei aquelas que possivelmente já foram fechadas.

Concordo que dentre as perguntas citadas a indentação não era o único problema e que uma resposta completa inviabilizaria o fechamento da pergunta como "erro de digitação", mas para efeitos de discussão podemos ater-nos somente ao problema de indentação.

Comment: Boa pergunta, é bom padronizarmos isto. E mais, poderia ser duplicata de alguma canônica?

Comment: @Maniero Poderia. Cogitei na possibilidade de definirmos uma canônica que tratasse sobre a indentação.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Minha opinião é **sim**, erros de indentação no Python devem ser considerados como erro de digitação.

A indentação compõem a sintaxe básica da linguagem. Errar indentação é errar a sintaxe e termos inúmeras perguntas que tratam sempre da mesma coisa, com respostas equivalentes, basicamente dizendo "você errou a indentação", não trazem benefícios para a comunidade.

**Mas e se a indentação não for o único problema?**

Acredito que deve ser fechada da mesma forma, porém, se respondida antes, sem problemas. Se a pergunta possui mais erros além da indentação e a mantivermos aberta, existe uma grande chance da pergunta se transformar em uma pergunta camaleão. O erro era de sintaxe, mas 10 minutos mais tarde o problema é o índice da lista que não existe ou uma mensagem exibida errada. Se alguém quer responder a pergunta já relatando todos os problemas, ótimo, isso provavelmente ajudará o autor da pergunta, incrementará na qualidade do tópico e, com certeza, ajudará outros usuários que, por ventura, cairão nessa pergunta. Porém, mesmo respondendo, para evitar o problema da pergunta camaleão, eu acredito que o fechamento ainda deva acontecer.

**Mas e se não foi erro de digitação, o usuário realmente desconhece a importância da indentação?**

Acontece, principalmente quando o usuário chega no Python já com alguns vícios de outras linguagens. As linguagens que utilizam as chaves, `{}`, para definir os blocos lógicos não levam em consideração a indentação, então existe a possibilidade da pessoa não estar condicionada a indentar o seu código, prejudicando-a no estudo do Python.

Com isso, juntando com o [comentário do Maniero](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7476/erro-de-indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-python-deve-ser-considerado-erro-de-digita%C3%A7%C3%A3o#comment28921_7476), não só a possibilidade de fechar a pergunta como "Fora do escopo > Erro de digitação", mas também como duplicata de uma pergunta/resposta canônica, que trata de forma completa, sobre a importância da indentação no Python.

**Resumindo...**

Ao meu ver a pergunta deve ser fechada como:

- Fora do escopo, erro de digitação, se não houver uma canônica;
- Existindo uma canônica, fechar como duplicata;

Em ambos os casos, o fato de responder, ou não, abordando todos os problemas da pergunta fica opcional.

Comment: Concordo plenamente.